# xhtml validation javascript

Tags: javascript, xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 


onmouseover="text.show('<br /><b>XXXXXX</b><br />')"
```

Validation Output: Error:

character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data

How can I fix it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&gt;` and `&lt;` instead of < and >, respectively.

Alternatively, enclose the code in a `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` section.

Comment: Sorry about that, StackOverflow substituted < for `&gt;`, just like you want.  ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can also keep your Javascript in a separate file and include it with `<script src="path/to/script.js"></script>` and avoid having to escape it at all.